# Android build failed: gensecimage_target

Tags: android, build

```
linking ../../../out/target/product/FJDEV061/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-fjdev/lk
../../../prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-ld: warning: /home/user/codes/LA.UM.6.6/LINUX/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.8/libgcc.a(bpabi.o) uses 32-bit enums yet the output is to use variable-size enums; use of enum values across objects may fail
../../../prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-ld: warning: /home/user/codes/LA.UM.6.6/LINUX/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.8/libgcc.a(_divdi3.o) uses 32-bit enums yet the output is to use variable-size enums; use of enum values across objects may fail
../../../prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-ld: warning: /home/user/codes/LA.UM.6.6/LINUX/android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.8/libgcc.a(_udivdi3.o) uses 32-bit enums yet the output is to use variable-size enums; use of enum values across objects may fail
generating image: ../../../out/target/product/FJDEV061/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-fjdev/lk.bin
generating listing: ../../../out/target/product/FJDEV061/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-fjdev/lk.lst
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 411148  388652  203212 1003012   f4e04 ../../../out/target/product/FJDEV061/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-fjdev/lk
../../../prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-objcopy -O binary ../../../out/target/product/FJDEV061/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-fjdev/lk ../../../out/target/product/FJDEV061/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-fjdev/lk.bin
generating listing: ../../../out/target/product/FJDEV061/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-fjdev/lk.debug.lst
generating symbols: ../../../out/target/product/FJDEV061/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-fjdev/lk.sym
generating size map: ../../../out/target/product/FJDEV061/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-fjdev/lk.size
generating stripped elf: ../../../out/target/product/FJDEV061/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-fjdev/lk_s.elf
cp -f ../../../out/target/product/FJDEV061/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/build-fjdev/lk_s.elf ../../../out/target/product/FJDEV061/obj/EMMC_BOOTLOADER_OBJ/../../emmc_appsboot.mbn
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/codes/LA.UM.6.6/LINUX/android/bootable/bootloader/lk'
make: Leaving directory '/home/user/codes/LA.UM.6.6/LINUX/android/bootable/bootloader/lk'

**[  0% 932/100297] Generating signed appsbl using secimage tool for msm8953**

**FAILED: gensecimage_target** 

/bin/bash -c "(rm -rf out/target/product/FJDEV061/signed ) && (SECIMAGE_LOCAL_DIR=vendor/qcom/proprietary/common/scripts/SecImage USES_SEC_POLICY_MULTIPLE_DEFAULT_SIGN=1 USES_SEC_POLICY_DEFAULT_SUBFOLDER_SIGN= USES_SEC_POLICY_INTEGRITY_CHECK=1 python vendor/qcom/proprietary/common/scripts/SecImage/sectools_builder.py -i out/target/product/FJDEV061/emmc_appsboot.mbn -t vendor/qcom/proprietary/common/scripts/SecImage/signed -g appsbl --config=vendor/qcom/proprietary/common/scripts/SecImage/config/integration/secimage.xml --install_base_dir=out/target/product/FJDEV061 > out/target/product/FJDEV061/secimage.log 2>&1 ) && (echo Completed secimage signed appsbl \\(logs in out/target/product/FJDEV061/secimage.log\\) )"
[  0% 935/100297] host C++: libsettings_32 <= vendor/qcom/proprietary/qcril/settingsd/commands/ConsoleSource.cpp
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
11:38:32 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (05:07 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**：this is due to the openssl version is 1.1 on my Ubuntu18.04,change the openssl version to 1.0 can solve the problem.